# Tableau workbook not displaying tabs from source file when migrated through Python Scipt

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, tableau-api

As a part of my assignment, i have been asked to migrate a tableau worksheet through a python script. The migration is successful but i do not get the tabs from source file in the output worksheet after the migration. Below are the images that will describe my position....

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

```html
'''
Created on Sep 12, 2016

@author: johnsoja
'''
import argparse
import Utils
import os

dev_server="http://ftc-wberfapp202"
dev_user="sys_dev_erfadmin"
dev_pwd="xyz"

stg_server="https://ftc-wberfapp501"
stg_user="sys_dev_erfadmin"
stg_pwd="xyz"

prod_server="https://PTC-WBERFAPP101"
prod_user="sys_pr_erf_admin"
prod_pwd="xyz"

scriptdir = "E:\\Program Files\\Tableau\\Tableau Server\\10.1\\bin\\";
tabcmdlogincmd = "tabcmd login -s {0} -t {1} -u {2} -p {3} --cookie";
downloadfilecmd = "tabcmd get \"{0}\" -f \"{1}\" ";
publishfilecmd ="tabcmd publish \"{0}\"  -r \"{1}\" --overwrite ";
tabcmdlogoutcmd = "tabcmd logout";
tmpFileLocation = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\approved\\";
tmpDatasourceLocation = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\datasources\\";

'''
Read from config file the data sources that are to be migrated.
'''
def readDataSourceConfig(configfilename):
    print('reading config file name ({0})'.format(configfilename))
    utils = Utils.ConfigUtil()
    datasources = utils.ConfigSections(configfilename)
    dataSourcesDict = dict()
    dataSourceNames = []
    for datasource in datasources:
        print("Datasources to migrate ({0})".format(datasource))
        dictionary = utils.ConfigSectionMap(configfilename, datasource)
        dataSourcesDict[datasource] = dictionary
        datasourcenm, connectionnm = datasource.split(":")
        dataSourceNames.append(datasourcenm)
    return dataSourcesDict, dataSourceNames
'''
Read from config file the data sources that are to be migrated.
'''
def readWorkbookConfig(configfilename):
    print('reading config file name ({0})'.format(configfilename))
    workbookprops = []
    with open(configfilename) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip() 
            workbookprops.append(line)
    print(workbookprops)
    return workbookprops

      
      
def getWorkbooksFromSourceSite(source_server,source_username,source_password,source_site,source_project,dataSourceNames,workbookprops):
    token, site_id, user_id = Utils.RestApiUtils.sign_in(source_site,source_server,source_username,source_password)
    workbooks = Utils.RestApiUtils.query_workbooks(token, site_id, source_project);   
    datasources = Utils.RestApiUtils.query_datasources(token, site_id)
    return workbooks, datasources
      
    
def uploadWorkbooksToDestinationSite(dest_server,dest_username,dest_password,dest_site,dest_project,workbooks,datasources,dataSourceNames,workbookprops,update_ds):
    os.chdir(scriptdir)
    print("********************")
    print("Logging into the Tableau Server")
    tabcmdlogincmdfrmt = tabcmdlogincmd.format(dest_server,dest_site,dest_username,dest_password)
    tabcmdlogincmdfrmt = tabcmdlogincmdfrmt+" --no-certcheck "
    print(tabcmdlogincmdfrmt)
    Utils.Commons.runCommand(tabcmdlogincmdfrmt)
           
    for workbook in workbooks:
        workbook_name=workbook.get("contentUrl")
        workbook_full_name=workbook.get("name")
        if workbook_name in workbookprops:
            workbookfile = "/workbooks/"+workbook_name+".twbx"
            outputworkbookfile = tmpFileLocation+workbook_name+".twbx"
            publishfilecmdfrmt=publishfilecmd.format(outputworkbookfile, dest_project,dest_username,dest_password)
            print(publishfilecmdfrmt)
            Utils.Commons.runCommand(publishfilecmdfrmt+" --no-certcheck ")
    print("********************")
    print("completed publishing workbooks")
    Utils.Commons.runCommand(tabcmdlogoutcmd)
    return workbooks, datasources

def stringComp(str_1, str_0):
    if(str_1 is None):
        str_1 = ""
    if(str_0 is None):
        str_0 = ""
    return str_1.lower() == str_0.lower()

def usage():
    print('\n This is the usage function: \n')
    print('NonProd-Staging-Prod-Loader -a -f <location of erf<stg/prod>migration.properties> -s <sitename> -p <projectname>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--filepath')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--sitename', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--destsitename', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--projectname', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--target', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--updatedatasource')
    args = parser.parse_known_args()[0]
    
    if(args.target=="PROD"):
        source_server = dev_server
        source_username = dev_user
        source_password = dev_pwd
        source_site = args.sitename
        source_project = args.projectname
    
        dest_server = prod_server
        dest_username = prod_user
        dest_password = prod_pwd
        dest_site = args.destsitename
        dest_project = args.projectname
        update_ds=args.updatedatasource
        print("moving site {0} from server {1} to server {2}".format(source_site, stg_server, prod_server))
        dest_ds_properties = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\migrationconfigs\\ds.prod.properties";
        dest_wkbk_properties = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\migrationconfigs\\wkbk.properties";
    
    if(args.target=="STG"):
        source_server = dev_server
        source_username = dev_user
        source_password = dev_pwd
        source_site = args.sitename
        source_project = args.projectname
    
        dest_server = stg_server
        dest_username = stg_user
        dest_password = stg_pwd
        dest_site =  args.destsitename
        dest_project = args.projectname
        update_ds=args.updatedatasource
        print("moving site {0} from server {1} to server {2}".format(dest_site, dev_server, stg_server))
        dest_ds_properties = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\migrationconfigs\\ds.prod.properties";
        dest_wkbk_properties = "E:\\Tableau_Deployment_Application_SVN\\migrationconfigs\\wkbk.properties";

    datasourceprops, dataSourceNames = readDataSourceConfig(dest_ds_properties);
    ##print("Data source names from properties")
    ##print(dataSourceNames)
    workbookprops = readWorkbookConfig(dest_wkbk_properties);

    
    workbooks, datasources = getWorkbooksFromSourceSite(source_server,source_username,source_password,source_site,source_project,dataSourceNames,workbookprops)
    
    workbooks, datasources = uploadWorkbooksToDestinationSite(dest_server,dest_username,dest_password,dest_site,dest_project,workbooks,datasources,dataSourceNames,workbookprops,update_ds)
     
   
    print("Completed Migration!!!!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because you have not specified the `--tabbed` option in your tabcmd publish command.
Change this line of code:

```
publishfilecmd ="tabcmd publish \"{0}\"  -r \"{1}\" --overwrite ";
```

to

```
publishfilecmd ="tabcmd publish \"{0}\"  -r \"{1}\" --overwrite --tabbed";
```